Unhashable type when calling HuggingFace topic model `topic_labels_` function
If I try to follow the topic modeling tutorial at: https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/en/bertopic
The first few lines give me an error:
from bertopic import BERTopic
topic_model = BERTopic.load("MaartenGr/BERTopic_Wikipedia")
topic, prob = topic_model.transform("This is an incredible movie!")
# error occurs on this line
topic_model.topic_labels_[topic]

Error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Don't expect us to follow the tutorial.  Explain what is from the tutorial and what is your own code.  The 'load' is returning a numpy array.  That cannot be used as a dict key - an intermediate knowledge of python and numpy should tell you that. Tutorials are well known for getting people lost in the weeds if they don't have the language  basics

@hpaulj I listed the tutorial just for context . The error can be reproduced with the four lines of code provided. If the tutorial is wrong, fine, but it would be helpful to understand why the topic result is not appropriate given it is exactly what is used in the tutorial. Shallow dismissals are rarely helpful.

You could do some debugging by checking the type of topic and topic_model.topic_labels_.  I'm responding as a common numpy user, without any knowledge of huggingface.  You may have to ask that communuty directly.

@hpaulj yeah, that's why I posted and tagged huggingface-transformers. I could not find good documentation on the topic_labels_ function that clued me in on this problem and am reaching out to the community for help

For clarity of others reading this, load does not return a numpy array; it returns a BERTopic model object. transform returns a numpy array

I found that topic_labels_ is indeed a mapping, a dict.  So the key can only be a str or int.  I wonder if transform should have only returned one topic rather than an array of them?  What's the shape of this array? Can you print it?

Many model pages use topic_model.get_topic_info()

To check what happens I would print separately topic_model.topic_labels_  and topic. Maybe this tutorial is an old one and they changed the API. You will easily find other tutorials to play with Bertopic.

Did you solve the problem?
